# How can I prepend a header to a file when using cat?

Tags: cat

If I have a file called `test.php` and its contents are

```
$a = "apple";    
echo PHP_EOL;
echo "  the value of \$a is $a" . PHP_EOL;
```

I want to cat the contents of `test.php` to STDOUT but I want to add a header string `<?php` to the beginning of the output. My desired outcome is to run a command like

```
% cat ..... test.php
```

desired output in terminal

```
<?php
$a = "apple";    
echo PHP_EOL;
echo "  the value of \$a is $a" . PHP_EOL;
```

I have tried assigning the string `<?php` to a variable and concatenating the variable with a here-string, e.g.

```
% php='<?php'       
% cat <<<$php
<?php
% cat <<<$php test.php 
$a = "apple";
echo PHP_EOL;
echo "  the value of \$a is $a" . PHP_EOL;
```

When I try to con`cat`enate a here-string to a file the here-string is ignored.
How can I insert a header into the STDOUT before the `cat`'ed file?

Comment: `cat - test.php <<<$php`?

Comment: @muru its seems like the command is backwards, but that works!

Comment: it's not backwards. `-` tells cat to print stdin input, which in this case should come before the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use the proper commands:

```
echo "<?php" && cat test.php
```

Comment: the reason I didn't use this form is because - once I got this command working - I then wanted to attach the STDOUT to a pipe. But I just tried your command wrapped in command group brackets and it works with a pipe, e.g. `{ echo "<?php" && cat test.php; } | php` thanks

Comment: @the_velour_fog: My pleasure! :)